# automation anywhere-For Each file in folder loop command stops after 223 counters also it stop entire module

Tags: foreach, automation, rpa, automationanywhere

Automation anywhere's For Each file in folder loop command stop after 223 counters also it stop entire task.
I am getting this issue in only 1 particular folder
although when I am looping through VBA its working fine

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have previously found the cause of this to be when the combined file path and file name exceeds a certain number of characters. I cant remember the exact amount sorry.

It stops the bot without any warning or error message.

Worth checking this out.

Comment: Yes, its work fine when i map share drive with local drive. i also found that it is issue with length of path.